# Link2sd showing app on sd but it is not

Tags: partitions, link2sd

I have a query regarding the way Link2sd is supposed to work. I came across this today. As the screenshots show when entering the Link2sd app. The app is supposed to be linked to the sd card, but, if you enter into the details of that link it show that none of them are on the sd card. The 3rd screenshot shows that everything is on the internal memory. I tried to unlink but it came up telling me that nothing is linked to begin with.
The screenshots are below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have gone part of the way to answer my own question. I noticed that it says `on SD Card` and not `Linked -> SD Card`. The app must therefore be moved to the SD Card no linked to it. I tried to move it back to the phone and although it allows me to go through the motions of moving it, even after a reboot it is still on the SD card. It seems like link2sd is moved to the SD card by default.